# Does HTTP differentiate between an empty body and no body?

Tags: http

Is there a practical difference between an HTTP request/response with an empty body and a request/response without a body? Does any version of the HTTP specification differentiate between the two, or are the two equivalent?

I guess it would also be useful to define the difference between the two cases. As far as I understand it, an empty body has a `Content-Type` header while an absent body does not. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header has nothing to do with whether or not a message body is present.  It simply tells you what the type of the body data is *if* a body is present.

An empty body is denoted by a `Content-Length: 0` header, or by a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header where the body consists of only a 0-sized chunk.  This is different than when there is no body at all.

[RFC 2616 Section 4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.3) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3) explain how to know when a message body is actually present or not.

RFC 2616:

```
   The rules for when a message-body is allowed in a message differ for
   requests and responses.

   The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the
   inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in
   the request's message-headers. A message-body MUST NOT be included in
   a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1)
   does not allow sending an entity-body in requests. A server SHOULD
   read and forward a message-body on any request; if the request method
   does not include defined semantics for an entity-body, then the
   message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request.

   For response messages, whether or not a message-body is included with
   a message is dependent on both the request method and the response
   status code (section 6.1.1). All responses to the HEAD request method
   MUST NOT include a message-body, even though the presence of entity-
   header fields might lead one to believe they do. All 1xx
   (informational), 204 (no content), and 304 (not modified) responses
   MUST NOT include a message-body. All other responses do include a
   message-body, although it MAY be of zero length.
```

RFC 7230:

```
   The rules for when a message body is allowed in a message differ for
   requests and responses.

   The presence of a message body in a request is signaled by a
   Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field.  Request message
   framing is independent of method semantics, even if the method does
   not define any use for a message body.

   The presence of a message body in a response depends on both the
   request method to which it is responding and the response status code
   (Section 3.1.2).  Responses to the HEAD request method (Section 4.3.2
   of [RFC7231]) never include a message body because the associated
   response header fields (e.g., Transfer-Encoding, Content-Length,
   etc.), if present, indicate only what their values would have been if
   the request method had been GET (Section 4.3.1 of [RFC7231]). 2xx
   (Successful) responses to a CONNECT request method (Section 4.3.6 of
   [RFC7231]) switch to tunnel mode instead of having a message body.
   All 1xx (Informational), 204 (No Content), and 304 (Not Modified)
   responses do not include a message body.  All other responses do
   include a message body, although the body might be of zero length.
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response, but this only answers half of the question. Does the specification differentiate between an absent body and an empty body?

Comment: How do the quotes in my answer not answer that for you?  It clearly does differentiate.

Comment: Sorry, you are right that my question did not ask this explicitly... Although the specification allows us to differentiate between the two cases, does it indicate whether it is okay to use them interchangably? For example, a HTTP 204 ("No Content") response is not supposed to have a body. Is it okay if an empty body is returned instead? HTTP GET is not supposed to have a request body. Is it okay if an empty body is returned instead? From the sound of things, it seems the answer is no. Do you agree?

Comment: They are mostly interchangable, except when they are not. For example, "*The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response*" and "*The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body*", etc.  A `GET` body is highly controversial, the RFCs *don't* clarify it. In fact, [RFC 7231 Section 4.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) explicitly says: "*A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.*"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an empty body may (or may not) have a `Content-Type` header. They could be treated the same way or differently depending on the application you're sending requests to.

An empty body could still serve a handful of purposes. Think of a survey where all the fields are optional. An empty body would indicate that a person intentionally decided to leave them all blank, and the application owner could, for instance, mark all these fields as "User would rather not answer", while ignoring absent response bodies.

Another useful implication for this same case (the optional fields survey) is that, even though you would have an empty body, anyone that had access to the POST request will be able to see that it was encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so even with an empty request, it is clear what kind of data is supposed to be received on a filled form, where an absent body would not give that kind of info.

Comment: I can see that point of view, but does the HTTP specification actually back up this interpretation (that an empty body is not equivalent to the lack of a body)?